# Unable to build egui project using 'trunk serve'

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, wasm-bindgen, rust-wasm, trunk-rs

I'm trying to learn a bit of Rust by building a small app using egui. The goal is to compile the project to wasm using trunk. However whenever I try to use `trunk serve` I get a bunch of errors. Specifically it seems that during the build process it is unable to build the dependency "mio-0.8.8" (*which is not directly included in the project*). The whole thing can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/FECXkRHK) (TL;DR mainly import and module errors).

My `Cargo.toml` for reference:

```
[package]
name = "test-app"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "rlib"]

[dependencies]
eframe = { version = "0.23.0", features = ["persistence"] }
rumqttc = "0.22.0"
serde = { version = "1.0.162", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.96"
wasm-bindgen-futures = "0.4.37"
gloo-timers = "0.3.0"

[target.'cfg(target_arch = "wasm32")'.dependencies]
tracing-wasm = "0.2.0"

[profile.release]
opt-level = 2 # fast and small wasm

[profile.dev.package."*"]
opt-level = 2
```

So far I've tried the following things (both on Windows and through WSL):

- (Re)installing the `wasm-bindgen-cli` as stated in trunk's Github repo
- `rustup update`
- Including `mio` in the `Cargo.toml` as a dependency
- (Re)installing the `wasm32-unknown-unknown` target
- Using `wasm-pack` (with this one even more dependencies aren't able to be built)

So far none of this has worked and I haven't yet found a solution elsewhere so I thought I'd ask here. Is there some specific thing I need to setup for this to work?

Comment: You likely won't be able to use rumqttc when compiling to WASM.

Comment: @kmdreko Oh I didn't realize. Is there maybe another MQTT crate that is able to compile to wasm?

Comment: "opt-level = 2 # fast and small wasm" The default of 3 is faster, and if you want small, use `"s"` or `"z"`.

Comment: FYI, if you're wondering why a dependency is being compiled, check the `Cargo.lock` file to see the dependency chain.